# Transferring a MySQL database from a shared host to a cloud provider

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-migration, digital-ocean

I am currently using a shared hosting provider for my database. It's about 15GB and would like to start to use something more robust (thinking of going with Digitalocean). Eventually I'll switch my site over as well, but for now I thought of just moving the database, then pointing my site (still on the shared hosting provider) to the new digital ocean server. After I believe things are good I'll eventually move the code over too.

I was reviewing this article here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers

and the idea seems good but I was concerned about missing some data and the whole strategy. I think my db is big enough that in the time it takes to copy the db and set it up, I'll miss the new transactions that take place (probably about 300 records nothing too much)

Would the solution be:

1. Copy database over, and set it up to make sure it's working
2. Update my PHP code to point to the new database
3. Run a MySQL script on the old database to get any records whose creation date is greater than x (I still think i'll get duplicate records here) or maybe any records whose primary key is >= x and <= y (so I can get the few hundred records that were added inbetween db xfers)

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe I fork the data so it goes to two databases at the same time temporarily, and then I can work on safely getting legacy data into the new db and only when everything is equal do I cut over?

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep both of them in sync, while the page is still running, would be a Master-Slave Setup, with the master being the old db until you switch your PHP-Code.

If you can't do that, you need to disable all write requests to your old db, while you are moving the data. Mysql can start in `--read-only` mode for that. You could of course just put up a maintenance page and block all access to the database.

Then get a fresh dump after the last write request, copy it over, and then point the PHP to the new DB. After that you can remove the maintenance mode.

You could use the approach you mention in 3., but that is risky. You would need to adjust auto-increment values, to make room for the missing entries.

Funny, just as I was about to edit this. SO got in read-only mode for a database transfer ;-)